# Call python file function from bash script

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash, shell

I have two files at the same location.

The first file is sh file and other is python file.

a.sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
a=1
b=1
if [[ $a -eq $b ]]
then
   call the python file function named callable with command line argument as value of a
   # python b.py $a
fi
```

b.py file

This file has many functions but I need to call specifically function callable:

```
arg = sys.argv[1]

def callable():
   print(arg)
```

How can I do that in script?

Comment: Combining shell and python scripts is always ugly, but if you have to do so, you should take a look at python's argparse module.

Comment: @EatPayBong: What is a _file function_ supposed to be? It would help if you would write concrete input for your program and concrete output. As it currently stands, I don't know what you want to achieve.

Comment: You need to consider your Python script as a CLI and use argparse (or equivalent) for that. Then you will need to implement the routing to your callable.

Answer (score 0):

add this at the bottom of your python script:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    globals()[sys.argv[1]]()
```

then in the bash script call the function you want

```
python b.py callable
# or
python b.py $a
```

Comment: This is probably more complex than what the OP is asking for, but the question is rather unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply looking for this?

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    callable()
```

By the by, you want to fix the quoting in your shell script.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
a=1
b=1
[[ "$a" -eq "$b" ]] && python b.py "$a"
```

See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable).

Comment: Initially I was thinking about providing this solution as well, but guessed maybe he/she wants to also call other functions from b.py